# Customize Angular SlideAndPush Directive with Menu offset

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I need to customize the Angular Slide.and.push directive found here: http://ngmodules.org/modules/slide.and.push which is of course inspired by the jquery version here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/slide-and-push-menus/

What I am trying to do is mimic the type of menu/sub menu system that SquareSpace (http://www.squarespace.com/) is using for their administrative dashboard (you'll have to create a free account to use it or go watch their promo video that shows it) where there is always a visible side menu along the left side of the page with menu icons. Upon clicking one of those icons, a secondary slide-out (push menu) slides out from the first (making it appear like the secondary menu is coming out of the first side menu.).

So far, when I add this slide.and.push directive the secondary menu slides out from the left side of the page over top of the primary side menu. I have tried adjusting the css a bit to no avail. Here's the original css for the side menu. So instead of it sliding out from the far left off screen...I need it to slide out from the primary always visible side menu which is 110px wide.

```
 /* Vertical menu that slides from the left or right */
.spmenu-left {
    left: -320px;
    border-right: 1px solid #65cff0; 
}
.spmenu-left a.spmenu-button {
    left: 320px;
    top: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; 
 }
```

And here's the code for the directive:

```
    angular.module("slidePushMenu", []).factory('slidePush',function () {

        var spmenuHorizontalHeight,
            spmenuVerticalWidth;

        spmenuVerticalWidth = 320;
        spmenuHorizontalHeight = 150;

        return {

            slide: function (menu, btn) {

                btn.toggleClass("active");

                if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-left")) {
                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-open")) {
                        menu.css("left", parseInt(menu.css("left"), 10) - spmenuVerticalWidth);
                    } else {
                        menu.css("left", parseInt(menu.css("left"), 10) + spmenuVerticalWidth);
                    }
                }

                if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-right")) {
                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-open")) {
                        menu.css("right", parseInt(menu.css("right"), 10) - spmenuVerticalWidth);
                    } else {
                        menu.css("right", parseInt(menu.css("right"), 10) + spmenuVerticalWidth);
                    }
                }

                if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-top")) {
                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-open")) {
                        menu.css("top", parseInt(menu.css("top"), 10) - spmenuHorizontalHeight);
                    } else {
                        menu.css("top", parseInt(menu.css("top"), 10) + spmenuHorizontalHeight);
                    }
                }

                if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-bottom")) {
                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-open")) {
                        menu.css("bottom", parseInt(menu.css("bottom"), 10) - spmenuHorizontalHeight);
                    } else {
                        menu.css("bottom", parseInt(menu.css("bottom"), 10) + spmenuHorizontalHeight);
                    }
                }

                return menu.toggleClass("spmenu-open");
            },
            slideForceClose: function (menu, btn) {

                if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-open")) {
                    btn.removeClass("active");

                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-left")) {
                        menu.css("left", parseInt(menu.css("left"), 10) - spmenuVerticalWidth);
                    }

                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-right")) {
                        menu.css("right", parseInt(menu.css("right"), 10) - spmenuVerticalWidth);
                    }

                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-top")) {
                        menu.css("top", parseInt(menu.css("top"), 10) - spmenuHorizontalHeight);
                    }

                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-bottom")) {
                        menu.css("bottom", parseInt(menu.css("bottom"), 10) - spmenuHorizontalHeight);
                    }

                    return menu.removeClass("spmenu-open");
                }
            },


            push: function (menu, btn) {
                var body, bodyLeft, bodyTop;

                body = angular.element("body");

                btn.toggleClass("active");

                if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-left")) {
                    bodyLeft = parseInt(body.css("left"), 10);
                    bodyLeft = (bodyLeft ? bodyLeft : 0);

                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-open")) {
                        body.css("left", bodyLeft - spmenuVerticalWidth);
                    } else {
                        body.css("left", bodyLeft + spmenuVerticalWidth);
                    }

                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-open")) {
                        menu.css("left", parseInt(menu.css("left"), 10) - spmenuVerticalWidth);
                    } else {
                        menu.css("left", parseInt(menu.css("left"), 10) + spmenuVerticalWidth);
                    }
                }

                if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-right")) {
                    bodyLeft = parseInt(body.css("left"), 10);
                    bodyLeft = (bodyLeft ? bodyLeft : 0);

                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-open")) {
                        body.css("left", bodyLeft + spmenuVerticalWidth);
                    } else {
                        body.css("left", bodyLeft - spmenuVerticalWidth);
                    }

                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-open")) {
                        menu.css("right", parseInt(menu.css("right"), 10) - spmenuVerticalWidth);
                    } else {
                        menu.css("right", parseInt(menu.css("right"), 10) + spmenuVerticalWidth);
                    }
                }

                if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-top")) {
                    bodyTop = parseInt(body.css("top"), 10);
                    bodyTop = (bodyTop ? bodyTop : 0);

                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-open")) {
                        body.css("top", "auto");
                    } else {
                        body.css("top", bodyTop + spmenuHorizontalHeight);
                    }

                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-open")) {
                        menu.css("top", parseInt(menu.css("top"), 10) - spmenuHorizontalHeight);
                    } else {
                        menu.css("top", parseInt(menu.css("top"), 10) + spmenuHorizontalHeight);
                    }
                }

                if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-bottom")) {
                    bodyTop = parseInt(body.css("top"), 10);
                    bodyTop = (bodyTop ? bodyTop : 0);

                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-open")) {
                        body.css("top", "auto");
                    } else {
                        body.css("top", bodyTop - spmenuHorizontalHeight);
                    }

                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-open")) {
                        menu.css("bottom", parseInt(menu.css("bottom"), 10) - spmenuHorizontalHeight);
                    } else {
                        menu.css("bottom", parseInt(menu.css("bottom"), 10) + spmenuHorizontalHeight);
                    }
                }

                return menu.toggleClass("spmenu-open");
            },


            pushForceClose: function (menu, btn) {
                var body, bodyLeft;

                if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-open")) {
                    btn.removeClass("active");
                    body = angular.element("body");

                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-left")) {
                        bodyLeft = parseInt(body.css("left"), 10);
                        bodyLeft = (bodyLeft ? bodyLeft : 0);
                        body.css("left", bodyLeft - spmenuVerticalWidth);
                        menu.css("left", parseInt(menu.css("left"), 10) - spmenuVerticalWidth);
                    }

                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-right")) {
                        bodyLeft = parseInt(body.css("left"), 10);
                        bodyLeft = (bodyLeft ? bodyLeft : 0);
                        body.css("left", bodyLeft + spmenuVerticalWidth);
                        menu.css("right", parseInt(menu.css("right"), 10) - spmenuVerticalWidth);
                    }

                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-top")) {
                        body.css("top", "auto");
                        menu.css("top", parseInt(menu.css("top"), 10) - spmenuHorizontalHeight);
                    }

                    if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-bottom")) {
                        body.css("top", "auto");
                        menu.css("bottom", parseInt(menu.css("bottom"), 10) - spmenuHorizontalHeight);
                    }


                    return menu.removeClass("spmenu-open");
                }
            }
        };
    }).directive("ngSlideMenu", [
        'slidePush', function (slidePush) {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                    return elem.click(function () {
                        var menu;
                        menu = angular.element("#" + attrs.ngSlideMenu);
                        return slidePush.slide(menu, elem);
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    ]).directive("ngPushMenu", [
        'slidePush', function (slidePush) {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                    var body, menu;
                    menu = angular.element("#" + attrs.ngPushMenu);
                    body = angular.element("body");
                    body.addClass("spmenu-push");
                    return elem.click(function () {
                        return slidePush.push(menu, elem);
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    ]).directive("ngSlidePushMenu", [
        "$document", 'slidePush', function ($document, slidePush) {
            var compile, link;
            compile = function (elem, attrs, transclude) {
                link.transclude = transclude;
                return link;
            };
            link = function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                return link.transclude(scope, function (clone) {
                    var body, btn, buttonClass, buttonText, classes, positionFix;
                    classes = (attrs.spmClass ? attrs.spmClass : "");
                    classes += " spmenu spmenu-" + (attrs.position === "right" || attrs.position === "left" ? "vertical" : "horizontal") + " spmenu-" + attrs.position;
                    elem.addClass(classes);
                    body = angular.element("body");
                    if (attrs.button) {
                        btn = elem.find(".spmenu-button").addClass("show");
                        buttonText = attrs.buttonText ? attrs.buttonText : "";
                        buttonClass = attrs.buttonClass ? attrs.buttonClass : "";
                        btn.addClass(buttonClass);
                        btn.append("<span class=\"" + buttonClass + "\">" + buttonText + "</span>");
                        positionFix = (attrs.fixTop ? "top: " + (parseInt(attrs.fixTop, 10) + elem.position().top) + "px; " : "");
                        positionFix += (attrs.fixLeft ? "left: " + (parseInt(attrs.fixLeft, 10) + elem.position().left) + "px; " : "");
                        btn.attr("style", positionFix);
                        if (attrs.button === "slide") {
                            $document.mouseup(function (e) {
                                if (!elem.is(e.target) && elem.has(e.target).length === 0 && !body.hasClass('modal-open')) {
                                    return slidePush.slideForceClose(elem, btn);
                                }
                            });
                            btn.click(function () {
                                return slidePush.slide(elem, btn);
                            });
                        }
                        if (attrs.button === "push") {
                            angular.element("body").addClass("spmenu-push");
                            $document.mouseup(function (e) {
                                if (!elem.is(e.target) && elem.has(e.target).length === 0 && !body.hasClass('modal-open')) {
                                    return slidePush.pushForceClose(elem, btn);
                                }
                            });
                            btn.click(function () {
                                return slidePush.push(elem, btn);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    elem.append(clone);
                    if (attrs.open) {
                        return btn.click();
                    }
                });
            };
            return {
                compile: compile,
                restrict: "E",
                replace: true,
                template: "<nav><a class=\"spmenu-button\"><i class=\"caret\"></i></a></nav>",
                transclude: "element"
            };
        }
    ]);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering I was able to solve this problem. I had to make some adjustments in the directive itself and then adjust the z-index of the slide menu to be less that that of the static primary side menu. See my comments in the slide function.

```
    slide: function (menu, btn) {

        btn.toggleClass("active");

        if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-left")) {
            if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-open")) {
                menu.css("left", -210); // Changed to this hardcoded value
            } else {
                menu.css("left", 110); // Changed to this hardcoded value
            }
        }

        if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-right")) {
            if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-open")) {
                menu.css("right", parseInt(menu.css("right"), 10) - spmenuVerticalWidth);
            } else {
                menu.css("right", parseInt(menu.css("right"), 10) + spmenuVerticalWidth);
            }
        }

        if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-top")) {
            if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-open")) {
                menu.css("top", parseInt(menu.css("top"), 10) - spmenuHorizontalHeight);
            } else {
                menu.css("top", parseInt(menu.css("top"), 10) + spmenuHorizontalHeight);
            }
        }

        if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-bottom")) {
            if (menu.hasClass("spmenu-open")) {
                menu.css("bottom", parseInt(menu.css("bottom"), 10) - spmenuHorizontalHeight);
            } else {
                menu.css("bottom", parseInt(menu.css("bottom"), 10) + spmenuHorizontalHeight);
            }
        }

        return menu.toggleClass("spmenu-open");
    },
```